# What is a way to change the AVD window size using IntelliJ

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-sdk-tools

IntelliJ doesn't give me a pop up that allows me to scale the window of the Android Virtual Device the way Eclipse does when I open one. I'm new to IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1):

Open your AVD manager, select the AVD for which you want to change the size. Select the Edit Button, in line "Skin" you can customize your AVD size. For example HVGA will make it fit to screen

Comment: My skin line only gives me a check mark box on weather to display skin with with hardware controls or not.

Comment: What version of intellij do u have? and also which API Level u r working on?

Answer (score 0):

Open `AVD Manager` > Select your `virtual device` > Select `Edit` >  `Devices` (2nd Row) select `ldpi, mfpi or hdpi` device or select according to inches show `2.7" or 10.1"`.